# Plot coloured by factor in R - colours looping not specifically assigned

Tags: r, plot

Apologies if this has been asked before, I tried looking but searching for assigning colours to plots in R is a very broad topic. Also, I have not added the data for you as there is quite a large amount of it (I don't think it will be needed since it is not an error message problem). EDIT with data sample:

```
      PC1                 PC2                colour
[1,] "-25.5987648792402" "3.41673760040586"  "blue" 
[2,] "-18.1520720669261" "2.09819717146663"  "green"
[3,] "-22.1308426042819" "3.46021550506459"  "green"
[4,] "-27.7950466967456" "-3.64374133124297" "gold" 
[5,] "-25.2414233662759" "-1.75802702655264" "green"
[6,] "-13.5641450885194" "2.70296369323088"  "green"
[7,] "-27.1954041315429" "6.44022518338822"  "blue" 
[8,] "-14.0474589982648" "3.00996494287365"  "red"  
[9,] "-40.1604532835109" "-27.6333759665025" "gold" 
[10,] "-26.6708536765817" "-5.0610016520552"  "red"  
[11,] "-21.4727890084845" "4.51825527258536"  "green"
[12,] "-21.2239456479504" "8.48862307072586"  "black"
[13,] "-25.0901196732896" "0.609916921307137" "blue" 
[14,] "-32.7132657746404" "-17.00161594225"   "gold" 
[15,] "-27.0815551977454" "10.5198515619958"  "black"
[16,] "-21.2961394099536" "9.53841507233795"  "black"
[17,] "-23.3675032692574" "3.36809622698634"  "black"
[18,] "-22.9904562811844" "11.9580087306051"  "black"
[19,] "-22.5073852494145" "1.30688136244357"  "gold" 
[20,] "-18.6259166632196" "5.51825251437074"  "gold" 
[21,] "-24.7138325079293" "-5.88117174408046" "red"  
[22,] "-19.2386902822007" "6.74347285527281"  "gold" 
[23,] "-29.3603972846236" "1.42048147132848"  "red"  
[24,] "-9.8526393614268"  "7.24233907420527"  "red"  
[25,] "-34.6289373905791" "3.655343260247"    "red"
```

I have been trying to plot principal components 1 and 2 with the points coloured by a categorical variable ($BIO). First I chose colours:

```
my.colours <- c("blue", "red", "green", "gold", "black")
names(my.colours) = c("WNT", "SHH", "G3", "G4", "unknown")
```

I assigned each $BIO factor a colour and created a column on csv (my data as list) for these $colours for each sample.

```
for (csv in 1:length(csvs)){
for (r in 1:nrow(csvs[[csv]])){
csvs[[csv]]$colour <- my.colours[which(csvs[[csv]][r ,]$BIO == names(my.colours))]}}
for (csv in 1:length(csvs)){
for (r in 1:nrow(csvs[[csv]])){
csvs[[csv]][r ,]$colour <- my.colours[which(csvs[[csv]][r ,]$BIO == names(my.colours))] }}
```

The output is correct:

```
csvs[[csv]]$colour [1] "blue"  "green" "green" "gold"  "green" "green" "blue"  "red"   "gold"  "red"   "green" "black" "blue"  "gold"  "black" "black" "black" "black" "gold" [20] "gold"  "red"   "gold"  "red"   "red"   "red"
```

Then I try to plot the graph using this column for colours.

```
for (csv in 1:length(csvs)){
for (pc in 1:length(pcas)){
pdf(paste("coloured 2D PCA plot of bio",types[pc],".pdf"))
plot(pcas[[pc]]$x[,c(1, 2)], col=csvs[[csv]]$colour, main =paste("2D PCA plot of ",types[pc]))
 dev.off()}}
```

The graph comes out with the right colours, but they are not assigned by which sample it is from (for example, there are 5 blue dots - there are only 3 blues in the sample). It seems that the samples have been assigned a colour by looping the my.colours rather than the $colour column? How can I fix this mess?

[image]

Thanks for your help,

Dominic

Comment: Even if you are not dealing with an error, a sample of your data is useful for answering, that way we can reach your current output and work from there to get your desired output.

Comment: I have now attached that

Comment: If you can show a bit of `csvs` and `pcas`, that would be ideal, as the problem seems to be how the colors in `csvs` are being assigned to the content of `pcas`.

Comment: I am not sure which parts of those lists would be useful to show. The data I showed above is cbind of pcas[[pc]]1:2 and csvs[[csv]]$colour.

Comment: The part of the data you shared has no problem ploting as expected, I suspect the problem you are facing depends on the way colors were assigned to $BIO. I can post an answer that includes a way to do this assignment that does not loop my.colors.

Comment: Thanks for your help Juan. I have decided to use 3D plots with plot_ly instead, which works as this was intended to.